# Defer query() in angular-rails-resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling a lists of all "tasks" using `Task.query().then(blah)`, and I want to run an `init` function before that one is run.

How do I defer the running of the query function?

Comment: Please show more of your code as is it isn't clear when you want the init to be called or what the problem is.  Generally speaking you can use $q to deal with async results but your particular scenario may or may not require that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it by just putting the query function inside of the init function. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.init = function(taskableId, taskableType, currentUserId) {
  $scope.task = {};
  $scope.task.taskableId = taskableId;
  $scope.task.taskableType = taskableType;
  $scope.task.creatorId = currentUserId;

  TaskResource.query({taskable_id: $scope.task.taskableId, taskable_type: $scope.task.taskableType}).then(function(result){
    $scope.tasks = result.reverse();
  });
};
```

Comment: Solved it. I just put the query function at the end of the init function.